# Appending Bezier paths using d3.js to current svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I am stuck in a problem for since last few days. As part of the assignment I had to implement a research paper which produces Bezier curves. I have gone to the extent of producing Bezier paths using d3-path. The paths are returning just fine. Problem arises when I try to append those paths in my current svg.

Here is the sample:

```
   var paths = []
    EB = new EdgeBundle(data, y, x, alpha, beta);
    EB.computeCentroidOfClusters(y);
    //for each row return the bezier path. These paths are stored in a 2d array. 
    data.forEach(function (row) {
        var color_ = myColor(row.class);
        paths.push(EB.returnBezeirs(row, color_));
    });
   
    for (var i = 0; i <= paths.length - 1; i++) {
        //var color = function (d) { return myColor(d.class) };
        for (var j = 0; j <= paths[i].length - 2; j++) {
            var color = paths[i][paths[i].length - 1];// the last position of paths is a color. So skipping that position on each iteration.
            if (j != paths[i].length - 1) {
                svg.selectAll('Path')
                .append('path')
                    .attr("d", paths[i][j])
                    .style("stroke", color)
                    .style("fill", "none")
                    .style("opacity", 0.5).node();
            }
        }
    }
    //slider initialization
    let slidertext = $("#slider-pcp-alpha-text-inner");
    $("#slider-pcp-alpha").unbind('input').on('input', (e) => {
        // console.log(e.target.value);
        slidertext.html("alpha: " + e.target.value);
        this.external(data, e.target.value, $("#slider-pcp-beta").val());
    });

    let slidertext_ = $("#slider-pcp-beta-text-inner");
    $("#slider-pcp-beta").unbind('input').on('input', (e) => {
        // console.log(e.target.value);
        slidertext_.html("beta: " + e.target.value);

        this.external(data, $("#slider-pcp-alpha").val(), e.target.value);
    });

    return svg.node();
```

This snippet is in the else condition where alpha and beta are not zero. The creation of this svg is being done before the if/else block. Snippet of it is as follows:

```
const svg = d3.create("svg")
    .attr("viewBox", [0, -50, this.width + 150, this.height + 150]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")");

// Draw the axis:
svg.selectAll("Axes")
    // add a g element for each dimension of the datset selected
    .data(dimensions).enter()
    .append("g")
    //translate the element to be positioned at right of the x-axis
    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x(d) + ")"; })
    //append other dimension axes towards its left, till the end
    .each(function (d) { d3.select(this).call(d3.axisLeft().scale(y[d])); })
    // add title to each axis
    .append("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("y", -9)
    .text(function (d) { return d; })
    .style("fill", "black")
```

For the if block the plot works fine since values of hyperparameters are 0 (both alpha and beta). Its been two days and I haven't been able to figure out the work around it. Any help or assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Really had to decipher your issue without a full snippet to reproduce the problem...  But from this snippet `svg.selectAll('Path').append('path')` it looks like you are trying to parent a `<path>` element to another `<path>` like:  `<path d="M0,0L100,100" stroke="steelblue" fill="none"><path d="M0,100L100,0" stroke="steelblue" fill="none" /></path>`.  This is illegal SVG and won't work.

Comment: Agree, probably confusion arose from the data binding pattern, which would have `.data(...)` in between. Use either `selectAll` and then `data`, or don’t use `selectAll`.